# How to make my ion-refresher working properly when user goes offline and back to online?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

When i unplug my dsl cable and plug it again, my ion-refresher doesnt work properly i dunno why.

I want to stop it while internet is OFFLINE and when internet is ON user can do it.

Here's the code :

```
doRefresh(refresher) {
    if (this.isOnline) {
      this.refreshData();
      this.getAssignedWarrents()
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Refresher completed.');
          refresher.complete();
        });
       }else {
    refresher.complete();
    }
  }
```

Comment: How do you update the `isOnline` property?

Comment: @Mathyn :   isOnline: boolean = navigator.onLine;

Comment: I noticed in your `doRefresh` method you do not update this value. Is it possible the `isOnline` property is not properly updated after the internet connection is restored?

Comment: How can i disable ion-refresher while internet is offline and then enable it while connected ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution would be to directly use the `navigator.onLine` property instead of the `isOnline` property:

```
doRefresh(refresher) {
    if (navigator.onLine) {
        this.refreshData();
        this.getAssignedWarrents().then(
            () => {
                console.log('Refresher completed.');
                refresher.complete();
            }
        );
    } else {
        refresher.complete();
    }
}
```

Your current code does not work because you never update the `isOnline` property. So the refresher never 'knows' the internet connection went offline or online.

However, a better way to do this is to directly disable the ion-refresher in your view.

An example of how you could implement this.

```
<ion-refresher 
    [disabled]="hasNoInternetConnection()" 
    (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
</ion-refresher>
```

Next in your controller:

```
hasNoInternetConnection(): boolean {
    return !navigator.onLine;
}

doRefresh(refresher) {
    // Your usual refresh. Note how we do not need to check if we are online here.
    this.refreshData();
    this.getAssignedWarrents().then(
        () => {
            console.log('Refresher completed.');
            refresher.complete();
        }
    );
}
```

This approach is better because we let Ionic handle disabling the refresher instead of checking it ourselves.

If `navigator.onLine` is not working reliably for you you can also use the [Network](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network) plugin provided by the Ionic team.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get compile errors? Runtime errors? I've had to improvise a bit because you did not share a lot of your code.

Comment: I see you have updated your `doRefresh` method but I cannot find a reference to the `hasNoInternetConnection` method I added. Also please share your HTML file.

Comment: Ah missed that one, thanks. Could you clarify what you mean when you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Loader doesnt stop while internet is turned off and thats it. Its allowed while net is OFFLINE also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194433/discussion-between-mathyn-and-zeljk0).

Comment: I updated the answer based on the chat. A working solution can be found at the top of my answer. However, the solution below should work in theory and might still be a preferred way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about Ionic environment, might be best way is to register handlers for Network like this:

```
  constructor(private network: Network) {}
  ...
  if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
    this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(
      async () => {
        await this.appOffline();
      },
      error => this.log.error('network.onDisconnect subscribe error: %j', error)
    );
    this.network.onConnect().subscribe(
      async () => {
        await this.appOnline();
      },
      error => this.log.error('network.onConnect subscribe error: %j', error)
    );
...
```